# Testing the significance between two correlations in Python.

Tags: correlation, python, bootstrap, pearson-r

I've seen some similar articles using R but I'm not sure how to implement this test in python.

Suppose I have two datasets, A and B (both contain 35 datapoints), and they predict some time series of C (also 35 datapoints).

A's correlations with C is r=0.27, B's correlation is r=0.34. This suggests that B explains about 4-5% more variance than A. How can I test to see if A and B are significantly different in predicting C?

I'm guessing some kind of bootstrap may work to see in the 5-95% tails of the distributions overlap, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, Philipp Singer has implemented some Python functions for calculating the statistical significance of differences between two dependent or independent Pearson correlation coefficients. Check out the [CorrelationStats](https://github.com/psinger/CorrelationStats) repository on GitHub.

In your example, if A and B are drawn from independent samples, then their relationship with C is independent of each another. You can therefore compare the two Pearson *r* values by applying a [Ronald Fisher z-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). This transformation normalises the *r* values so they are directly comparable.

Conversely, if A, B and C are obtained from the same sample of the population, then you need to account for the fact that each variable is not independent. CorrelationStats also includes a couple of methods for comparing two dependent correlation coefficients.